# reading excel and attaching it in mail body using java

Tags: java, excel

I have a job that runs and creates an Excel workbook with summary of users (in first sheet) and user details (in next sheets) using Java.

I need to send the summary sheet created (i.e. the overall summary details in table format) in the e-mail body (**not as attachment**). Is there any way to read the Excel sheet directly and copy its contents into mail body? Can someone show an example code ? I tried using `mimebodypart()` and `multipart()` but I am not able to put it in mail body, it is going as attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct approach for embedding the excel sheet to the email body.

One approach would be to set the content type as text/html, loop through the contents of the excel and form an html string using `<table>` directives of html.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what data is in table 
I assume it is a table with some value in second sheet

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("d:\\1\\2\\2.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < numberOfSheets; sheetIdx++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
            List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();
            for (XSSFTable t : tables) {
                System.out.println(t.getDisplayName());
                System.out.println(t.getName());
                System.out.println(t.getNumerOfMappedColumns());

                int startRow = t.getStartCellReference().getRow();
                int endRow = t.getEndCellReference().getRow();
                System.out.println("startRow = " + startRow);
                System.out.println("endRow = " + endRow);

                int startColumn = t.getStartCellReference().getCol();
                int endColumn = t.getEndCellReference().getCol();

                System.out.println("startColumn = " + startColumn);
                System.out.println("endColumn = " + endColumn);

                for (int i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
                    String cellVal = "";

                    for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn; j++) {
                        XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                        if (cell != null) {
                            cellVal = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        }
                        System.out.print(cellVal + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

            }
        }
```

with this you can get all data of the table and you can add it into your email body formatting it.

I got this as result

This is my table in 2nd sheet

```
    two three   four    five    six seven
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
```

**I got this with help of table** 
xssf:

```
  startRow = 7
endRow = 18
startColumn = 7
endColumn = 13

    two three   four    five    six seven   
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf    
    abd dfdsfs  fghf    afr dfdsfs  fghf
```

Comment: Thanks Kishan.I am able to read data using above code but when I try to add it to mail body using mimebodypart() ,it is not coming correctly.Again it is adding as attachment...

Comment: Can you please post your sample code so that i can review.

Comment: And one important thing :If this answer has solved your question,You should accept the answer by ticking green rite mark in the left side of the answer so that this answer will be useful for every body. Please follow stack overflow tradition of apprising good answers .